# Object oriented programming get function doesn't return correct array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

This is the code that i have problem with. It reads pin codes from text file and it should save them into array with object oriented programming. when I try to display the values in while loop it works fine, but when i try to do it outside while loop, it doesn't work. As for example in the second to last line cout doesn't work.

```
   #include "branjeDatoteke.h"
    #include "parametri.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;
    void branjeDatoteke() {
    Parametri pin[101];
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("pin.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {

                pin[i].setPin(line);
                cout << pin[i].readPin() << endl;
                //cout << line << '\n';
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
        cout <<"tole more delat: "<< pin[2].readPin() << endl;
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

and this is the CPP file for my Parametri class

```
#include "parametri.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void Parametri::setPin(string pin) {
    this->pinKoda = pin;
}

string Parametri::readPin() {
    return pinKoda;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly use dereference on `this` in the `this->pinKoda = pi` assignment, you can directly assign like so `pinKoda = pi`.

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a loop inside a loop...

With the first iteration of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { ... }
```

you will read *all* of the contents of the file because of the inner loop

```
while (getline(myfile, line))
```

The second iteration of the outer `for` loop will not read anything at all, and neither will the next 99 iterations.

That of course means that `pin[2]` (or indeed `pin[1]` to `pin[100]`) will be initialized. Only `pin[0]` will be, and it will end up with the *last* value from the file (because the inner `while` loop will overwrite it over and over again).

---

You should change your code to a *single* loop, perhaps something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100 && getline(myfile, line); i++)
{
    pin[i].setPin(line);
}
```

Note that this loop might end before you fill in all elements of the `pin` array. You should probably have a `std::vector` instead of an array, if there's less (or more!) data in the file.